# Why is Cocoa.h imported in generated XCTestCase in an iOS project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, code-generation

After generating an `XCTestCase` subclass for my iOS project, I noticed `#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` is added by default.

After looking around, I've found that iOS projects should instead import `Foundation.h`.

My question is, **why is `Cocoa.h` imported by default, even though it's an iOS project, not an OS X one?**

Is there any additional setup option, which I need to specify so the generated code is for iOS? (Obviously I could just edit that line, but I wonder if it can be done by default).

I'm using XCode 6.2

Answer (score 1):

That's because when you created the file, the OSX option was selected. Happened to me the first time too.
Just make sure you're under iOS option when you create a new file.
Hope it helps